# Change iOS7 Status Bar Colour programmatically, mid-run?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I’m trying to change the Status Bar colour mid-run, i.e. not when a controller is loaded. I change the view’s background colour, so I need to change it from the black to white and vice versa.

I know that I can change it using `preferredStatusBarStyle` and the setting in the plist, but as far as I can see that’ll only set it on first launching the view controller. I’d like to change it, for instance, when I hit a button.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Go to your application Plist and add this as new row & set it as NO.

  ```
  View controller-based status bar appearance  NO
  ```

Add a bool to determine state of `UIStatusBar` colour & add a Toggle method

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL black;


-(void)toggleStatuSBar:(id)sender{

    if(black) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
        black = NO;

    }else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
        black = YES;
    }
}
```

here is a Sample ScreenShot

- When Menu is Closed, the colour is White.

  [image]
- When Menu is Open The colour is Black

  [image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This way you can change viewController's StatusBar independently.

Comment: This has been deprecated in iOS 9. Is overriding the UIViewController method the only way now? That isn't ideal.

Comment: @Arcrammer : The Original Post was answered more than an year ago by me, when the API was well functioning. It would be better to edit the answer & add the new api code.

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 3:

1. Go to your application Plist and add this as new row & set it as NO.

`View controller-based status bar appearance  NO`

2.

White: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Black: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default`