# UITableView Content not Passing Under Status Bar

Tags: uitableview, swift, statusbar

I have a UITableView set in a UIViewController that displays a grouped UITableView. It looks great sitting there but when I go to scroll up all of the text just passes straight through the status bar. I've done some searching around and it seems to be a common problem. I've tried embedding the view in a navigation controller but that doesn't give me the result I want. I want to have a status bar that is semi-transparent such that my content is visible through the status bar but doesn't interfere with it. Could someone steer me in the right direction?

Essentially I want the translucent look when embedded in a Navigation Controller but without the extra Navigation Bar at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the default ViewController and replace it with a TableViewController that you drag into the Storyboard from the Object Library you get this problem. Fix programmatically using:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Preferably replace 20 with myViewController.topLayoutGuide...

Comment: If that does not work look through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Add following thing in your .plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance  NO
```

and use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

More information : [Change iOS7 Status Bar Colour programmatically, mid-run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827349/change-ios7-status-bar-colour-programmatically-mid-run)

Comment: I did as you suggested but I didn't see any change. Here is what my window looks like now: http://imgur.com/rip9BNU notice how it is completely transparent. I want to have a solid opaque/semi-transparent status bar such as you'd find in Apple's iOS 8 Game Centre app.